How to start second KDE session from a virtual terminal
Running Ubuntu 24.04. I have a KDE environment, and want to open up a KDE session for a second user in a different virtual terminal. I have googled and found that after logging in from a different virtual terminal the command startx -- :2 opens up a new GUI session. But, it opens a gnome session, not a KDE one. The gnome session, not too surprisingly, doesn't work well, there is no task manager and programs started hang for some time before opening, or some eventually crash.
I also tried startx /usr/bin/kded5 -- :2, which does open up a gui but without any manager running. Maybe I need a custom .xinitrc to start a manager? How would that be done? There are some plasma files in ~/.config, should some of those be in an .xinitrc file?
The first time I tried this it somehow worked great - after logging in as the first user the kde login screen was still showing in a virtual terminal, and I just logged in as the second user and everything worked. I don't know what was different after I rebooted, but now VT0 is a blank shell, not a login screen.

To get 2 user sessions log into one with the GUI, then choose "switch user" from the panel. This will return you to the login screen without closing the initial user. Log in as the second user and use ctrl-alt-f* to switch between virtual terminals.
